# How do I remove <p> </p> tags in typo3 RTE text content elements?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, rte

Hello I'm getting crazy around a dummy problem: how to remove paragraph tags < p > that RTE (in Typo3 6.1.7) adds oafter saving some text contents. I wish to add some images here to better explain this funny thing but I can't since I've not (yet) enough reputation.

BTW I put the images on an external site:

http://s16.postimg.org/uqbu40fut/rte_ptags_1.jpg

http://s16.postimg.org/7q56roi11/rte_ptags_3.jpg

The first image is a text entered in RTE; the second image (not shown here for the same reputation matter) is the same text shown in the "<>" raw view; the last image is what I see in raw view AFTER saving the content element.

I think that I must do something in the template or in the Typoscritp settings to remove these < p > useless tags... But what ??

Comment: why do you bother? Usually our content should be wrapped in p-Tags or other block elements, if you add tables f.e. I would not recommend to change this behavior. What is the _real_ problem?

Comment: I don't know what is the real problem (the < p > tags shift down the text in FE). I think that nobody can help me. Probably it's a dummy issue and it's due to my incompetence in Typo3. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those `<p>` tags are enabled by default because in most cases you want your Text wrapped in propper HTML markup. However, typing your question into google, gets me to this two lines of Typoscript, wich I just tested on a 6.1.7 and which seem to do the job:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.dataWrap >
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines >
```

Comment: I have googled for this configuration some hours, and tested a lot of stuff, but nothing seems to works. Also, as your suggested, these lines of TS (as well the TS of vish). These infamous < p > tags are fixed on my elements and nothing can sends them away.

Comment: When I add those 2 Lines to my main template i dont have any < p > tags in the rendered HTML in the frontend. TYPO3 6.1.7.

Comment: I'm sure that what you say is true. I worked a long time on Typo3 4.X and I always changed setting on RTE. This time I cannot, don't know why. Maybe for some misconfiguration on my installation. I'll do everything again from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Remove Class Of <p class="bodytext">

lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.addAttributes.P.class =

// Remove P tag
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap >
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines >

//Remove Extra Figure Tag of Image
tt_content.image.20.renderMethod = figure
tt_content.image.20.rendering.figure
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it in a past project was to use [format.stripTags](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Format/StripTags.html). Basically you can tell which tags you want and thus exclude unwanted tags, like the `<p>` tag you mentioned.

Here you'll see how it works:

```
<f:format.stripTags allowedTags="<p><span><div><script>">
    <p>paragraph</p><span>span</span><div>divider</div><iframe>iframe</iframe><script>script</script>
</f:format.stripTags>
```

It excluded the `<iframe>` tag, thus giving us this result:

```
<p>paragraph</p><span>span</span><div>divider</div>iframe<script>script</script>
```

In your case you would just leave the `<p>` tag out.